# How to use stored procedure in C# to return a list of results?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

Here is my stored procedure:

```
    CREATE  Proc UpdateChecklist
(
    @TemplateId As INT
) as
begin
    select MF.CheckListDataId from TemplateModuleMap TM
    inner join ModuleField MF 
    on TM.ModuleId = MF.ModuleId
    where TM.TemplateId = @TemplateId and MF.CheckListDataId not in
    (select cktm.CheckListDataId from ChecklistTemplateMap cktm
    inner join ChecklistData ckd
    on cktm.CheckListDataId = ckd.Id
    where cktm.TemplateId = @TemplateId)
end
```

So I expect to have a returned list of `CheckListDataId` here. I'm trying to use `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` but not succeed yet. How can I return a list of `CheckListDataId` here? Do I need to modify my stored proc? I'm pretty new to sql.

Any suggestion? This is an ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Comment: see `Database.ExecuteDataSet` overloads.

Comment: specifically `public virtual DataSet ExecuteDataSet(
 CommandType commandType,
 string commandText
)` should suit you.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: Can you please give me a specific example?

Comment: Thats not a stored procedure, thats a SELECT. What specific issue are you having? No data returned? incorrect data returned? error message?

Comment: Assuming the `select` is part of your procedure , you could pass `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and the `Name` of the procedure as the two parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Stored Procedure will return you a **resultset** and you can process that however you want in your C#.

I would call the procedure from inside my model class in this way:

```
DataTable loadLogFilterData = SQLHelper.ExecuteProc(STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME, new object[] { 
    //Parameters to Stored Proc If Any
                });
```

Then I have a SQLHelper Class inside which I create the SQL Connection and have the delegate methods to call the stored procedures.

```
public static DataTable ExecuteProc(string procedureName, Object[] parameterList, string SQLConnectionString) // throws SystemException
        {
            DataTable outputDataTable;

            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = OpenSQLConnection(SQLConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    if (parameterList != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < parameterList.Length; i = i + 2)
                        {
                            string parameterName = parameterList[i].ToString();
                            object parameterValue = parameterList[i + 1];

                            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameterName, parameterValue));
                        }
                    }

                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                    DataSet outputDataSet = new DataSet();
                    try
                    {
                        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(outputDataSet, "resultset");
                    }
                    catch (SystemException systemException)
                    {
                        // The source table is invalid.
                        throw systemException; // to be handled as appropriate by calling function
                    }

                    outputDataTable = outputDataSet.Tables["resultset"];
                }
            }

            return outputDataTable;
        }
```

You have treat every output from a stored procedure as a resultset no matter what it contains. Then you need to manipulate that result set in your Model to populate the desired data structure and data type.